# dotnet client's traffic not similar while using hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast

I am using the `3.11.2` version with `4 nodes` clyster setup. One of my applications was written in java another one in dotnet. When I check the java client's cluster, all nodes have almost the same network traffic. On the other hand at dotnet client's cluster 1 node using, for example, 200MB traffic other 3 only 3-5MB. Java cluster configured for cache, dotnet cluster using map.
How can I fix this?

PS : I know 3.11.2 is old version but I don't like to upgrade it unless I hit a pug which force me to do it.
Mehmet